# Get date format as Test_170727_1608.txt.gpg

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am trying to send attach a file thats been created and send as an email using "exec master..sp_sendSAM" in an SSIS 2005 flow.

This is what I tried

```
'Test_'+ convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 12)+'.txt.gpg' = Test_170727.txt.gpg
'Test_'+ convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 105)+'.txt.gpg' = Test_27-07-2017.txt.gpg
'Test_'+ convert(varchar(24), getdate(), 113)+'.txt.gpg' = Test_27 Jul 2017 17:25.txt.gpg
```

**But I actually want is = Test_170727_1608.txt.gpg**

Can someone help me get to this please as I seems bit stuck. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 'Test_'
    + right(datepart(yy,GETDATE()),2)
    + RIGHT('0' + cast(datepart(m,getdate()) as varchar(2)),2)
    + RIGHT('0' + cast(datepart(d,getdate()) as varchar(2)),2)
    + '_'
    + RIGHT('0' + cast(datepart(HOUR,getdate()) as varchar(2)),2)
    + RIGHT('0' + cast(datepart(mi,getdate()) as varchar(2)),2)
    + '.txt.gpg'
```

Comment: Thanks Keith this works nicely to my code I wrapped it correctly this time with TSQL and ran perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't get it with one convert but you can with two:

```
DECLARE @D as datetime 
SET @D= GETDATE();

SELECT 'Test_' + 
        CONVERT(char(6), @D, 12) +'_'+ 
        REPLACE(CONVERT(char(6), @D, 14), ':', '') + 
        '.txt.gpg'
```

Result: `Test_170727_0946.txt.gpg`

Comment: This is giving me an error saying "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable."

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it's 2005. Edited my answerr.

Comment: I'm sure this is a good answer. I just like being straight forward so I don't have to google my own code!